# Java array reverse not working

Tags: java, arrays

I suppose to reverse 10 different numbers that input by user. For example, if user put '34 82 49 102 7 94 23 11 50 31' for the input the result should be '31 50 11 23 94 7 102 49 82 34'. However I keep getting 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 for the result and I do not even get input box from scanner. Added image for more detail.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ReverseNumbersFor
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int [] reverseNumbersWhile = new int [10];
    printReverse(reverseNumbersWhile);
  }

  public void reverseNumbersWhile(int num[])
  {
    System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers : ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int [] input = num;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
      input [i] = in.nextInt();
    } 
    System.out.println(input);
  }

  public static void printReverse(int [] value)
  {
    for (int i = value.length - 1; i >=0; i--)
    {
      System.out.print(value[i] + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

[Code image with result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V8z0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] number = new int [10];
    printReverse(reverseNumbersWhile(number));
}
public static int[] reverseNumbersWhile(int[] input){
    System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers : ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
      input[i] = in.nextInt();
    }  
    //System.out.println(input);
    return input;
}

public static void printReverse(int[] value){
    for (int i = value.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
      System.out.print(value[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i have to use 'public void reverseNumbersWhile(int num) ' method....

Comment: @NeedHelp Check my edited answer. Only problem is that if you use the number in your main function. It will print 0's because you are passing to the function as pass by value method

Comment: @NeedHelp You have to use a static method. Because you cannot call a non-static method from a static method

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling the reverseNumbersWhile method. You're initializing an array called reverseNumbersWhile and then passing it to a method that just prints its values, which have all only been initialized to zeros.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have already pointed out what's wrong with your code. Here's another way of reversing using Java 8 [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) -

```
 public static int[] reverse(int[] a) {
    return IntStream.range(0, a.length).map(i -> a[a.length - 1 - i]).toArray();
 }
```